# Как просмотреть структуру xpi файла?

Tags: firefox-extension

Как просмотреть структуру .xpi файла ?
Как просмотреть внутренности .xpi файла ?
Как получить исходники Firefox расширения из .xpi файла ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPI-файл (*.xpi) — ZIP-контейнер, который содержит manifest.json файл и другие данные. Можно открыть любым зип архиватором.